# How to implement image upload support to a WYSIWYG html editor?

Tags: image, upload, wysiwyg

I am having trouble finding out a good way how to add image support to a WYSIWYG editor such as Stack Overflow is using. I understand it is HTML, and when adding an image, an `<img>` tag with the link to the image is going to be created and added to the body. However, what if I would like the users to be able to upload(ideally paste/D&D) images from the file system.

I noticed that Stack Overflow is using an imgur widget for that, so I suppose the image will be uploaded to imgur and then the imgur link is going to be used. However, my usage is internally in a company and some of the images are confidential, therefore they should not leave the intranet.

I appreciate any help I can get :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am just researching right now for a project I am about to do. It is a question of guidelines/patterns/architecture not necessarily my specific implementation so I don't see why would that be a problem.

Comment: Your question doesn't fit in the scope defined for StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic You don't even know where to start, so there are too many possible answers and so the best one is that you pick an existing solution instead of creating your own one.